# Springdoc update from Springfox result in 406 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, springfox, springdoc

I am migrating springfox to spring doc and get 406 error.
Similar like this: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/950
Only the swagger-ui got the issue but the /v3/api-docs can generate the json/yaml file.

After I debug the DispatcherServlet in doDispatch, an exception occur during getHandler.

The exception is:

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation.

Below is the picture of the debug. If I debug further, the request /swagger-ui/index.html is actually mapped to an endpoint that accept /{param1}/{param2} that generates application/json. So, how to map the swagger path to the resource instead of a controller? Thank you

Spring boot version 1.5.x (spring 4.x). springdoc version 1.6.14.

[image]

Comment: what version are u using? what version of spring boot? is it the same as in that github issue?

Comment: I'll update in the question.